# Inkscape 0.91 shows Font Size 14 in dropdown and 17.5px in XML Editor

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I am using Inkscape 0.91 for Ubuntu and am working on a template. The unit chosen for the document is pixels, the font size for the menu items Open Sans 14px all caps. But when I check the font size in the XML editor it states it is 17.5px . Why is that?

Screenshot:

[image: Imagewize Homepage]

And document properties:

[image: Inkscape document properties]

Comment: if it would be 14pt it would be 17.5 px using 90 DPI as I do according to W3C http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units . But I picked px as default value and for dimensions so that should not be the case now should it?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Inkscape does seem to deal with pt size differently though. See https://gist.github.com/jasperf/e8f9f2d28bdc21ec672d and then there still is my question.... If I set all at px why would the menu then still pick pt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems fonts used to be in px, but earlier this year after a five year [debate](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/168164) has been turned into pt. And on hover I finally saw it too:

[image: font in pixels]

As I chose pixels for the document as default and for dimensions Inkscape calculates a value in pixels and adds it to the source code. This leads to odd numbers sometimes like 28.6666 or the likes. This is rather unfortunate as I am using this for webdesign. Will have to think about the general setup here.

Comment: I read through that debate and I'm more confused than ever. From what I can tell, print users are arguing it should be pt, and web folks are arguing px. But in 2015, I think that just makes things worse...as both pt and px are used for both. Seems that inkscape should simply have the font size adhere to the document unit preference.

Comment: I asked in the linked issue to make the font unit modifiable.