# How do I make the font size value within my SVG equal the font value size defined within Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

When I set my font size to 100 within Inkscape, the font size saved within the SVG is not set to 100.  In the attached example, the font size within the SVG is set to 133.333px.  Why?  It seems Inkscape and the SVG are using different scales/units of measurement for the font size.  I'm doing some SVG programming, and it would be MUCH easier if I could get these two values to match.  Is there a setting within Inkscape that will make these values the same?

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Wyatt

[image: question screenshot example]

Comment: This question seems a duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61111/inkscape-0-91-shows-font-size-14-in-dropdown-and-17-5px-in-xml-editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text size is in pixels in the XML.  However, the default text size is measured in points in Inkscape 0.92.  You can set the units in Inkscape's Preferences to pixels if you want.

[image]

Comment: Actually, the size is labelled as px, but px in user units. So the numbers in the XML are given in mm (real-world units), if the default document is used.

Comment: See also: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Units_In_Inkscape

Comment: @moini - interesting, and yet utterly confusing at the same time ;)  So if the text units should be set to millimetres instead, can I hire an assassin to shoot the person who was responsible for this?

Comment: This preference change solved my issue.  Now all my units of measurement are the same.  Thank you for your help.  My default Inkscape document is measured in pixels.  As shown here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/cano5iwip1w5jac/Screen%20Sharing%20Picture%20July%2022%2C%202019%20at%2011.28.40%20AM%20PDT.png?dl=0

Comment: @BillyKerr No! Please don't kill anyone here. The default document is A4 (and thus, measured in mm), and this issue is usually of interest to people who a) use software that doesn't interpret SVG correctly, who b) handcode their graphics, or who c) are adventurers who look in every corner of Inkscape and wonder what's going on... A change back to the previous template (which was based on px) has been requested already, but wasn't considered a serious issue - or maybe it was just too hard to decide... https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues/203 - at least, no developer ever replied.

Comment: @Moini I can see that now. If I choose the Desktop template when creating a new document, then changing the Text Size units to pixels seems to work as expected. This is good to know about. Thanks for the extra info.

Comment: There seems to be no "Text units" in Inkscape 1.2 / Preferences / Tools / Text, and it seems to be always "px" now?

Comment: @sdbbs - you can still change the text units when using the Text Tool, in the control bar along the top in 1.2.2. It's no longer in the preferences.  The default is pixels.

Answer (score 3):

To have the same units displayed in the XML as in the font size dropdown in Inkscape 0.92.4, set the Text units to 'mm' (**if you're using the default document template, not a custom one**). See screenshot in Billy Kerr's post for where to find it.